# Infinite series still convergent when odd and even terms are interchanged

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

The question is deifned as Let $\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_{n}$ be a convergent series, let $\sum_{0}^{\infty} b_{n}$ be its rearangement obtained by interchangeing each even numbered term with the odd numbered term immediately following it: $a_{1}+a_{0}+a_{3}+a_{2} + ...$

Show that $\sum_{0}^{\infty} b_{n}=\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_{n}$

How could they possibly not be the same? how do you even start to prove this? converge sub-sequences of $a_{n}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** Apply the definition. You know that $\sum_0^\infty a_n = L$. Show that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_0^N b_n = L$.

Comment: What he said... Don't use fancy things like subsequences.  Use the definition for convergence of a series.